# ActionController::MissingFile but the file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7 app, running on two different machines (The same application runs on two separate machines without sharing anything. In one instance reports are displayed without issue, So, I assume the code works just fine)  where I need to render some PDF files. The code is simple, as shown below.

```
task_list = CompletedTaskList.find(params[:id])
send_file "#{Rails.root}/reports/completed-task_report-#{task_list.code}.pdf",
          disposition: 'attachment'
```

In one instance everything works fine (so this is not a code issue) but in the second one I can't open the files.

First I had an `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /application/reports/completed-task_report-111.pdf` So, I updated the rights on the `reports` directory but now I get `ActionController::MissingFile: Cannot read file /application/reports/completed-task_report-111.pdf` even if the file is there.

The file is not readable.

```
"path: /application/reports/completed-task_report-111.pdf"
"file: true"
"readable: false"
```

As suggested below, I tried to change the access permissions to the directory `chmod -R 777` but that didn't solve the problem and the file remains unreadable.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Beware that inserting user input into a file path like this leaves you open to exploits.

Comment: "running on two different machines" - unless the file system is shared, only one machine will have the file, the other one will complain about missing file. "file is there" - which is where? you have two places where it could be. should probably use some kind of a storage solution: activestorage, carrierwave, shrine.

Comment: I understand now. I thought you were loadbalancing one app. `MissingFile` can still be a permission issue, rails checks for `File.file?(path) && File.readable?(path)` when raising that exception. maybe just 777 everything just to see if that solves it, including files and directory.

Comment: @Alex, The files are indeed not readable. Unfortunately, `777` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you post the result of `ls -la /application/reports/completed-task_report-111.pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message, if you posted the complete msg, says it could not open '/application...'  That file does not exist in the root of the file system I would bet.  There is something wrong with your file name specification I think.  It looks ok but there is something else....

Looking at my code I have always just specified the file in a send_file relative to Rails.root.  IAW I would just use:
send_file "reports/completed-task_repo..."

Comment: Thanks, but the file exists.
I have copied/pasted the path in the error massage and opened the file with `cat`.

Comment: My point was that the file in the error message as you posted is in the system root filesystem not the Rails.root directory.